# How do I do SQL Server mapping with a new Desktop application written in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm

In 2 weeks I will be starting a new job as a software developer in a company that currently does not employ any professional programmers.  My first task will be to rewrite a Excel/VBA application in C#, with an SQL back end.

I am currently a C# developer but we don't use a database back end; previously I was a database administrator but I didn't program.  I have very little experience at joining up the two worlds.

*What are the options for modelling the database access in a C# desktop application with a SQL Server back end?*  I would want to have some separation between the layers (database, logic, user interface).

Comment: recommended reading: **[What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)**

Comment: I can edit it so that it doesn't ask for pros/cons and doesn't mention solutions if you think that would be better @gnat

Comment: @PaulRichards do you know about the Entity Framework? If not just check it out.

Comment: Is this nuget, @Knerd?

Comment: @PaulRichards what do you mean? For the EF check here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907

Comment: @PaulRichards to address the rest of your question, check on WPF and MVVM. That should help you ;)

Comment: Well some people may think its too broad but to me its a perfectly valid question.  I don't care if there are many possible answers, I'll look at the ones with the most rep.  And if you can't answer it in a few paragraphs, post a link to a resource.  Anyway, the answers and comments have helped me - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you want is domain driven design, In simple terms separation of concerns. Read about it and you are good to go. To keep it simple since you say yo new, Just have User Interface layer in its own project, a service / logic layer in its own project. a data access layer in its own project and other layers depending on the project. For the data access i would recommend you use Entity Framework to bind with your database (preferable database first option since you have db admin background). Now read and get familiar with Linq and Entity Framework and i think you are good to go.

Comment: I have started learning the entity framework and I think this will save me time, thanks.

In future I am going to learn WPF but for now am going to stick to winforms.

Answer (score -1):

You definitely should design your application with discrete layers - data access, business logic, UI etc.

However, I'm going to go against the trend and advise you not to use Entity Framework for your data access layer.

An [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) should be purely a mapper between database and POCO classes. In my eyes, EF breaks the single responsibility principle by trying to do too much - caching, change tracking, lazy loading etc etc. All this extra functionality places too heavy a load on performance.

Instead, I suggest that you should use a simple micro-ORM such as [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), [Peta Poco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) or [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite). Your choice will depend on the exact functionality required and whether you have an existing database. My vote would go to OrmLite, as it supports code-first design (generating database elements from C# class definitions) and async/await functionality.

Comment: Srp applies to a class not a framework.  And its a principal mot a hard and fast rule.

Comment: So what's DbContext if not a class?

Comment: My key point still stands though - don't blindly choose EF just because it is the "official Microsoft Orm" unless you really need all it's features.

Comment: SRP is useful when you are maintaining the class; you're not worrying about maintaining DbContext yourself, someone else is, you should only care that it works.  What you claim is your main point appears as a couple of sentences in your entire answer, you just spout out that you believe EF does "too much" and should just avoid it in favor of ORMs which do less.